# SMB Discovery - Discovering shared folders on the network

Tags: windows, smb, network-discovery

Is there a way where we can discover all the devices in the network with shared folders?
Typically like how the network folder works in windows.
Would any java/android library support smb discovery??

Comment: Just use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/shareenum and use the IP range for starting and ending and give it some time. You might have to run elevated as administrator so keep that in mind too. Otherwise there are tools such as nmap that may do this see https://nmap.org/nsedoc/scripts/smb-protocols.html.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT the range of ip addresses can be dynamic ! is there a specific server point to be hit to retrieve all the devices supporting smb share on the network?

Comment: Hi - Yes, even if IP addresses on the "network with the shared folders" are assigned out dynamically, you can use this tool. If you have a network, then that network is on a subnet IP address range e.g. `192.168.1.1 - 192.168.1.254` so use the entire range and use that with the tool link to download I provided.

Answer (score 0):

jNQ (Java) and NQE (C) from Visuality Systems both support this.

Comment: What would be the server point to be hit to discover all the devices on the network?